# PHP function to run a function (based on string)?

Tags: php, function

Is there a PHP function or command that runs a function based on a string, array, or similar? Basically, if the string "time" is passed, I want `time()` to be returned. Ideally, I'd like this to also support passed parameters. I just want this to be for individual functions, though. I DON'T want to `eval()` an entire block of code, for obvious reasons.

Does anything like this exist--or, preferably--is it native in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try call_user_func() http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

The first argument is a string representing the function name. The second argument can be a single argument, or an array of arguments.

Edit:

It will even support native functions like time(), as you asked. Try it out like so:

```
echo call_user_func( 'time' );
```

Comment: Ahh, this looks like it's what I'm looking for! Thanks! Before I accept your answer, though, does it only support defined functions? Or are all functions (such as `time()`) supported?

Comment: It definitely does support all functions!

Answer (score 3):

You can call a function using a variable containing the function name as well as pass any parameters to that function.  Try:

```
<?php

$func = 'strtoupper';

$res = $func('i am uppercase');

echo $res; // I AM UPPERCASE
```

See [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as well.  As mentioned, [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func) works too.

For safety, you can call:

```
if (function_exists($func)) { ... }
```

before calling the function based to make sure you avoid errors.  You can use `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getNumberOfParameters` to determine the number of parameters the function accepts as well.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! I never knew about this. Thanks for the idea! Though the other answer answers the question better, I may end up using this instead, so +1 to you!